# undefined local variable or method `params' for # in controller when writing multiple conditions for drop down options

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a view with static drop down select_tag as:

```
= select_tag(:option, options_for_select([['Option1', 2], ['Option2', 3], ['Option3', 4]], :selected => params[:option] ), class: 'form-control')
```

My controller is:

```
   def create_report
     @report = Report.create_report(params[:id], params.merge(account: current_account, user: current_user))
     @report.execute
   end

  def execute
    @items = []
    if params[:option] == "Option1"
      current_date = @start_date
      while @end_date >= current_date
        daily_items = Option1.by_account(@account).active.includes(:company, :primary_contact, :primary_addr).where('date(txn_date) = ? ', current_date)
        @items << Item.new(items: daily_items, date: current_date) unless daily_items.empty?
        current_date += 1.day
      end
    elsif params[:option] == "OPtion2"
      current_date = @start_date
      while @end_date >= current_date
        daily_items = Option2.by_account(@account).active.includes(:company, :primary_contact, :primary_addr).where('date(txn_date) = ? ', current_date)
        @items << Item.new(items: daily_items, date: current_date) unless daily_items.empty?
        current_date += 1.day
      end

    end

  end
```

When i am writing a condition for only one condition, it is working fine. But when I write a condition for each Options,as written in controller **execute** method. It is showing error as:

*undefined local variable or method `params` for #*

Comment: In Which line you get that error? also from where `params[:pid]` come from?

Comment: Sorry it is params[:option], edited, once check...